# Creating groups with unlimited space for users

Tags: php, mysql

I want to program a system with which users can create their own teams, which other users can join. The problem is, I don't know how to handle it, that if a user creates a team, this team can accommodate unlimited users.

My user database looks like this: id, name, email, password and team

If something is incomprehensible, please ask.

Thank you very much.

With kind regards
Max

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'c' FROM your_table_of_users_for_a_team WHERE teamid = 1` - If the count is more than how ever many, don't add the user ? You're overthinking it

Comment: I think this question was closed inappropriately. It's a legitimate question about modeling many-to-many relationships. Some people are too strict about Stack Overflow guidelines. I am voting to reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the beauty of relational databases.

You need *three* tables:

```
users: id, name, email, password -- no team reference here

teams: id, name

membership: user_id, team_id
```

Each row in `membership` references one user and one team.

A given user can have multiple rows in `membership` as they join more teams.

A given team can have any number of rows in `membership`, indicating the players on that team.

When using relational databases, you need to think in terms of *sets* of rows.

---

Re your followup question in comments:

You could insert this way:

```
INSERT INTO membership
SET user_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users WHERE name = 'hpotter'),
    team_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM teams WHERE name = 'gryffindor');
```

Or you could use variables:

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @user_id FROM users WHERE name = 'hpotter';
SELECT MAX(id) INTO @team_id FROM teams WHERE name = 'gryffindor';

INSERT INTO membership SET user_id = @user_id, team_id = @team_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try and if I encounter any problems I will get back to you!

Comment: I have one last Question. How can i get the id from users and teams and write it into the membership database? I tried this: "INSERT INTO membership (user_id, team_id) AND SELECT id FROM users AND SELECT id FROM teams". but it didnt work.